# Send MailGun email with Attachment from Google Drive in C#

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, mailgun

I can send emails with attachments from my local computer just fine but can't figure out how to send attachments of files that are in Google Drive.

Can the file be send with a simple path in the below code if sharing permissions are set? If so, how do I get that path?

How can I send a file without sharing permissions?

Here is my MailGun Send code...

```
        public static void Send()
        {
            RestClient client = new RestClient();
            client.BaseUrl = new Uri("https://api.mailgun.net/v3");
            client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("api", "abc123");
            RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
            request.AddParameter("domain", "mail.dealopo.ly", ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.Resource = "{domain}/messages";
            request.AddParameter("from", "Name <test@sandboxcabc123.mailgun.org>");
            request.AddParameter("to", "myemail@msn.com");
            request.AddParameter("subject", "Hello");
            request.AddParameter("text", "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!");
            request.AddParameter("html", "<html>Inline image here: <img src=\"cid:Capture.jpg\"></html>");
            request.AddFile("inline", Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop", "Capture.jpg"));
            request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(@"C:\Users\Jeremy\Desktop", "Local File.pdf"));

            request.AddFile("attachment", Path.Combine(@"WHAT PATH DO I USE??", "Google Drive File.pdf"));

            request.Method = Method.POST;
            var response = client.Execute(request);
        }
```

Comment: If you want to _attach_ a file to an email, that consists of essentially taking the file content, finding a valid separator that doesn't exist in any of the email parts, putting the separator after the email body followed by the byte content.  Is that what you want to do with google drive?  In order to preserve permissions you probably just want to add a _link_ to google drive in the _body_ of your email.  In case you really want to put the google drive content in email, you may need to download the file and then attach it from a local source.

Comment: Could you clarify if you want to attach a copy of the file to your attachment, a link to the Google Drive file or a "embedded" web preview of the file?